# Repeating form fields and updating to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

any help would be most appreciated, I am rather new to Rails.

I have two models a Shopping List and a Product. I'd like to save/update multiple products to a shopping list at a time.

The suggested changes are not updating the models. I've been googling and is "attr_accessor" or find_or_create_by the answer(s)?

Attempt 1 - Existing code

Error

```
> unknown attribute 'products_attributes' for Product.
Request
Parameters:

{"_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"3BgTQth38d5ykd3EHiuV1hkUqBZaTmedaJai3p9AR1N2bPlHraVANaxxe5lQYaVcWNoydA3Hb3ooMZxx15YnOQ==",
 "list"=>
  {"products_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>{"title"=>"ten", "id"=>"12"},
     "1"=>{"title"=>"two", "id"=>"13"},
     "2"=>{"title"=>"three", "id"=>"14"},
     "3"=>{"title"=>"four", "id"=>"15"},
     "4"=>{"title"=>"five", "id"=>"16"},
     "5"=>{"title"=>""},
     "6"=>{"title"=>""},
     "7"=>{"title"=>""},
     "8"=>{"title"=>""},
     "9"=>{"title"=>""},
     "10"=>{"title"=>""}}},
 "commit"=>"Save Products",
 "id"=>"7"}
```

Attempt 2 - no errors the page reloads and none of the expected fields are updated. In earnest, I am Googling around and copying and pasting code snippets in the vain hope of unlocking the right combo.
Added to Products mode

```
    class Product < ApplicationRecord
      attr_accessor :products_attributes
      belongs_to :list, optional: true
    end
```

```
<%= content_tag(:h1, 'Add Products To This List') %>
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :products do |pf| %>
    <%= pf.text_field :title %><br>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag "Save Products" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Back To List", lists_path %>
```

list controller

```
    def update
        #render plain: params[:list].inspect
        @list = List.find(params[:id])
        if @list.products.update(params.require(:list).permit(:id, products_attributes: [:id, :title]))
            redirect_to list_path(@list)
        else
            render 'show'
        end
```

list model

```
    class List < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :products
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
    end
```

original do nothing - product model

```
    class Product < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :list, optional: true
    end
```

Comment: Using `n.times` isn't the way to do it. The documents you want to read are [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [Action View Form Helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Comment: you can use nested_fields and gem 'cocoon' for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a user to be able to select products and place them on a list you want a many to many association:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :products, through: :list_products
end

class ListItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :lists, through: :list_products
end
```

This avoids creating vast numbers of duplicates on the products table and is known as *normalization*.

You can then select existing products by simply using a select:

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :product_ids %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:product_ids, Product.all, :name, :id) %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Note that this has nothing to with nested routes or nested attributes. Its just a select that uses the `product_ids` setter that's created by the association. This form will still submit to `/lists` or `/lists/:id`

You can whitelist an array of ids by:

```
def list_params
  params.require(:list)
        .permit(:foo, :bar, product_ids: [])
end
```

To add create/update/delete a bunch of nested records in one form you can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` together with `fields_for`:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :products, through: :list_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :products do |pf| %>
    <%= pf.label :title %><br>
    <%= pf.text_field :title %>
  <% end %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Of course `fields_for` won't show anything if you don't seed the association with records. That's where that loop that you completely misplaced comes in.

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def new
    @list = List.new
    5.times { @list.products.new } # seeds the form 
  end

  def edit
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    5.times { @list.products.new } # seeds the form
  end
  # ...

  def update
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    if @list.update(list_params)
      redirect_to @list
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def list_params
    params.require(:list)
          .permit(
            :foo, :bar,
            product_ids: [],
            products_attrbutes: [ :title ]
          )
  end
end
```

Required reading:

- [Rails Guides: Nested forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)
- [ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
- [fields_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

Comment: Hi Max, your write up is phenomenal and I am very much appreciative of your guidance. I am rather embarrassed to say I am not intelligent to plumb the rest in. I've updated my source in my original post. It would seem like the form action/name/id's are not a close match to the expected model. Would you be kind enough to take a look. I've inspected the update output and created a update action, however, I cannot seem to get the form elements to be correct.

Comment: It not that you're dumb at all. This is something every rails beginner struggles with an it took me many attempts to actually get this right when I was learning. Doing more complex forms where you're CRUD'ing multiple records at once is quite complex and something you might want consider circling back on later when you have a better foundation of understanding.

Comment: You're pretty close though. Instead of `@product = @list.products.update(product_params)`. You want `@list.update(list_params)`.

Comment: The whole deal with nested attributes is that you don't have to really do anything on the controller layer besides whitelisting the attributes. Its all done by the setter in the model. So when you update the parent it automatically takes care of all the nested records.

Comment: thank you for all of your help and equally important your words of encouragement. I now have a working script, many many thanks!

Comment: I've been sat at the screen for 80 minutes trying to get "update" to work, failing miserably.